# Access denied error on window.moveTo()

Tags: javascript

I have a window that is composed of a frameset. When I launch it, I have to
resize it, thus:

```
<script language="javascript"> window.onload = function(){window.moveTo(0,0);  window.resizeTo(400,500); }</script>
```

but then when I ran it in IE 8, it gives me the "Access denied" error in the 
window.moveTo() code.

I also tried using it as:

```
<body onLoad="moveWindow(this);"><script language="javascript"> function move(obj){   obj.moveTo(0,0);obj.resizeTo(400,500);  }
```

but still gives me the error.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you been able to run that successfully with other browsers?

Comment: yeah, its ok with firefox though..

Comment: @tinks, did you get any solution to your problem? Because, I am facing the same issue and trying hard to find a solution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this problem which works for me is to add a simple html file with only "Loading.." text in it. Load it first, move the window, and then load the intended URL:

```
var win = window.open('blank.html');
win.moveTo(50, 50);
win.location = 'http://www.google.com';
```